# splitting up html returned from GET request on a certain class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a `GET` request which is returning two divs see below:

```
$.get('releases', function(data){    
   console.log(data);
}
```

`data` returns the following html

```
<div class="release">
    <a href="link-1/">
        <img src="image-1.jpg">
        <h3>Test playlist 1</h3>
        <p>This release is a playlist</p>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="release">
    <a href="link-1/">
        <img src="image-1.jpg">
        <h3>Test playlist 1</h3>
        <p>This release is a playlist</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

I am wondering how I can split the response up on the div with the classname `release`. The way I see it is that I would have each of the release divs and their contents in an array that I could then loop through and add responsive classes etc.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  What would splitting the response do?

Comment: I "think" `data.find('.release).each(function(){});` might work. Maybe not.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup by splitting the response means i could put each `release` into another div with responsive settings. As it currently is I cannot do that

Comment: @Leeish That was actually what I tried. It didn't work , but maybe I will try again, it has been a long day!

Comment: What kind of "API" is that, which returns you HTML instead of JSON?

Comment: @RamisWachtler It's not an API. It is set up with wordpress and using another routing system for the front end. Don't ask :-)

Comment: @phantom maybe you should use something like this [WP-API](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/). At least it's still better than doing it the "HTML way". In the long term, this may save you a lot of time.

Comment: @RamisWachtler thanks! i never knew about this. The wp is kind of out of my hands but I'll suggest it! thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing that, why not add the classes in the document ready function?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').find('.release').each(function(){
         $(this).addClass( "myClass yourClass" );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the data into a jquery Object and then use .find() to get the div's. Then loop through them to do what you need to do.

```
$.get('releases', function(data){    
   $(data).find('.release').each(function(i, el){
      var $release = $(el);
      $release.addClass('some-class'); 
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly what you were doing but this will loop through each div.

https://jsfiddle.net/ewsdnow6/

```
var data = '<div class="release"><a href="link-1/"><img src="image-1.jpg"><h3>Test playlist 1</h3><p>This release is a playlist</p></a></div><div class="release"><a href="link-1/"><img src="image-1.jpg"><h3>Test playlist 1</h3><p>This release is a playlist</p></a></div>';

var html = $.parseHTML(data);
$(html).each(function(){
    console.log($(this));
});
```

Comment: However while this may or may not answer your question I would agree with comments above with looking for a better way. So long as it doesn't add unnecessary code bloat for a single thing you are trying to do. This code should loop through each element and you can do whatever you want, add/edit classes, move in your DOM, etc. $(this) will be the release div.